# Proper way to evaluate a multilabel classifier in keras using sklearn

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel data, with 8 labels for each instance.

The shape of validation data is `(1000,8)`, when i use the data, `keras fit_generator` show me good result.

```
Epoch 1/5
 - 445s - loss: 0.3608 - acc: 0.8522 - val_loss: 0.3528 - val_acc: 0.8538
Epoch 2/5
 - 382s - loss: 0.3579 - acc: 0.8528 - val_loss: 0.3528 - val_acc: 0.8538
Epoch 3/5
 - 377s - loss: 0.3555 - acc: 0.8525 - val_loss: 0.3516 - val_acc: 0.8538
Epoch 4/5
 - 375s - loss: 0.3550 - acc: 0.8526 - val_loss: 0.3509 - val_acc: 0.8538
Epoch 5/5
 - 373s - loss: 0.3515 - acc: 0.8528 - val_loss: 0.3454 - val_acc: 0.8538
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fd7d2fca2b0>
```

But when i check the accuracy usig `sklearn` using following code
`y_pred = model.predict_generator(valid_gen,steps=step_size_val)`
 I got this error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets`

So i do

```
y_pred[y_pred>=0.5] = 1
y_pred[y_pred<0.5] = 0
y_pred=y_pred.astype(int)
```

But now i got `zero` accuracy

Comment: It is probably expected, for multi-label classification [sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) measures subset accuracy: the set of labels predicted for a sample must exactly match the corresponding set of labels in y_true.

Comment: it mean for 100% accuracy (theoratically);  if y_true is `[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]` then y_pred should be `[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]`. So how keras is giving good accuracy and what is the solution

Comment: yes, if one of the label does not match then for this particular example score is zero.

Comment: Keras is calculating like this:  if `y_true= [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]` and `y_pred = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]` then accuracy is 0.875 (7 out of 8 is correct).

Comment: though other matches, let suppose y_true is  `[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0] ` and y_pred is `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` , then result should be 7\8 or zero?

Comment: What this result should be that depends on your use case, You have both the metrics it's up to you, how you want to measure your model's performance.

Comment: I just checked a  [blog](https://blog.mimacom.com/text-classification/) , they use `loss='binary_crossentropy',`  and `metrics=['categorical_accuracy']` for multilabel. And i am using simple `["accuracy"]` as metrics as in this  [blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/) , so which one should i opt